# Elegant way to perform array properties comparison using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Any clue about how to perform the following code using Linq?

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i < array1.Count; ++i)
{
    if (!array1[i].Name.Equals(array2[i].Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `bones` to iterate `array1` and `array2`?

Comment: For starters, use `(for int i = ...)`

Comment: `Select` + `SequenceEqual`

Comment: That depends on the index, so i'd keep using the  `for`-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably worth double checking to ensure that `array1` and `array2` are at least as long as bones.Count... so

```
Enumerable
 .Range(0, new[] {bones.Count, array1.Length, array2.Length}.Min())
 .All(i => array1[i].Name.Equals(array2[i].Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array1.All((a, i) => a.Name.Equals(array2[i].Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if all names in the arrays are equal  at the same index you can use:

```
bool allEqualNamesAtSamePosition = array1
    .Zip(array2, (arr1, arr2) => new { arr1, arr2 })
    .All(x => string.Equals(x.arr1.Name, x.arr2.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

But normally i prefer a plain `for`-loop if something depends on the index. In my opinion LINQ even decreases readability in that case.